Error "Cannot find module when using npm link in TypeScript
I'm developing a Node.js app (MyApp) and a Node.js module (MyTools) simultaneously on a Windows 2019 server with node v18.16.0.
You can find the full code on GitHub: https://github.com/zero2411/myapp
I'm using npm link to add MyTools to MyApp, but I'm encountering an error on line 1 in myapp.ts:
Cannot find module 'mytools' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Directory Structure
myapp/
├── node_modules/
│   └── mytools/ (linked)
│       ├── mytools.d.ts
│       ├── mytools.d.ts.map
│       ├── mytools.js
│       ├── mytools.ts
│       ├── package.json
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── myapp.ts
├── myapp.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── tsconfig.json


MyTools Setup
Created the folder mytools.
Initialized the module:
> npm init -y
> tsc --init

Updated tsconfig.json:
"declaration": true,
"declarationMap": true

Created mytools.ts:
export class MyTools {
    // Class implementation
}

Transpiled TypeScript to JavaScript:
> tsc

Linked the module globally:
> npm link

MyApp Setup
Created the folder myapp
Initialized the app:
> npm init -y
> tsc --init

Linked mytools to myapp:
> npm link mytools

This added mytools to node_modules as expected.
Created myapp.ts and imported MyTools:
import { MyTools } from "mytools";

Problem
Cannot find module 'mytools' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Additional Information
Both MyApp and MyTools have their tsconfig.json files configured to handle TypeScript.
The node_modules directory in MyApp correctly includes mytools.
I've tried several solutions, but the error persists.
What am I missing or doing wrong?
